# Change home directory to USB in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to store all the 'working' data on an USB drive. So I can unplug it and use it on another machine, having all the 'working' data ready.

I don't think it is a good idea to change the home directory permanently to the USB drive, since it may not be plugged in. What I'm looking for is a command I can enter in the shell, which will work for the current shell session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as root:

```
mount --bind /media/usbdrive /home/you
```

Comment: You also need to set the ownership to the target user.

Comment: @terdon, could you explain how to do that? or link to some documentation?

Comment: @flavio.donze in the simplest form, `sudo chown -R flavio:flavio /media/usbdrive`. That's assuming that `/home/you` (or `/home/flavio` or whatever) ios also owned by your user.

Comment: with the addition of terdon's input, it seems to work so far.